# Ошибка: Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, wordpress, warning

Немного покурочил класс `Walker_Nav_Menu` в wordpress, цель была заменить стандартные классы меню, на свои.
Вот код:

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    // здесь дописываю к массиву с классами свои значения.
    // назначаем классы li-элементу и выводим его
    $item->classes['my_item_class'] = 'page-header__nav_item'; // класс li элемента 
    $item->classes['my_link_class'] = 'page-header__nav_link'; // класс a элемента 
    if($item->current) {
        $item->classes['my_current_class'] = 'page-header__nav_link--active'; // класс a элемента текущего пункта меню 
    }
    $class_names = ' class="' .esc_attr( $item->classes['my_item_class'] .' '. $item->classes['parent_class'] ). '"';
    $output.= '<li ' .$class_names. '>';

    // назначаем атрибуты a-элементу
    $attributes.= !empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' .esc_attr($item->url). '" class="' . $item->classes['my_link_class'] . ' ' . $item->classes['my_current_class'] . '"  ' : '';
    $item_output = $args->before;
```

массив с классами `$item->classes`, после этих манипуляций имеет вид:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => menu-item
    [2] => menu-item-type-custom
    [3] => menu-item-object-custom
    [4] => current-menu-item
    [5] => current_page_item
    [6] => menu-item-home
    [my_item_class] => page-header__nav_item
    [my_link_class] => page-header__nav_link
    [my_current_class] => page-header__nav_link--active
)
```

Возникает ошибка:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'my_item_class' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/u0205156.plsk.regruhosting.ru/blog.itconcentrate.pw/wp-content/themes/gragon/functions.php
>   on line 221

Ну и соответственно по всем элементам массива `classes`, добавленными мной.
В чем проблема?

Comment: это значит что ключ не существует 'my_item_class'

Comment: @ L. Vadim, ну как не существует? он же там есть!!! `print_r($item->classes)` это показывает!!! классы добавляются к элементам меню, только `warning` вылазиет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это должно решить проблему. Как я понял, проблема связана с версией PHP.

```
 if(!isset($item->classes['my_item_class'])) // фикс
 {
    $item->classes['my_item_class'] = 'page-header__nav_item'; // класс li 
 }
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрался. Нужно проверять существует ли необходимый ключ в массиве, затем формировать строку с классами элементов. Так как не все пункты меню имеют такие классы как `parent` и `current`, необходимо проверять есть ли соотвествующии ключи в массиве.